# RSpec system test fails when broadcasting later in a background job (ActiveJob and ActionCable)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails, actioncable, rails-activejob

Using rails 7.1.2 and rspec-rails 6.1.0

**TL;TR** Tests fail only when broadcasting "later" in background jobs by using `config.include ActiveJob::TestHelper` in the rails_helper.rb file, but they pass when not using it.

```
# app/models/my_class.rb

class MyClass < ApplicationRecord
  after_update_commit :broadcast_update_user

  private

  def broadcast_update_user
    broadcast_update_later_to('ts_channel_id', ...)
  end
end
```

```
# system/my_class_spec.rb

RSpec.describe 'MyClass system tests', :type => :system do
  it 'should broadcast', :js => true do
    @my_instance = FactoryBot.create(:regular_instance)

    visit my_path

    # simulate record update
    @my_instance.update!(:value => 'YO!!!')
  
    expect(page).to have_css('span.value-target', :text => 'YO!!!', :exact_text => true, :count => 1)
  end
end
```

If I run the above spec by using the following RSpec configuration, then the test ***fails***.

```
# rails_helper.rb

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include ActiveJob::TestHelper

  config.before(:suite) do
    ActiveJob::Base.queue_adapter = :async
  end
end
```

If I run the above spec by using the following RSpec configuration, then the test ***passes***.

```
# rails_helper.rb

RSpec.configure do |config|
  # config.include ActiveJob::TestHelper

  config.before(:suite) do
    ActiveJob::Base.queue_adapter = :async
  end
end
```

How can I solve the testing issue related to broadcasting later in a background job?

---

**RSpec logs**

By using `config.include ActiveJob::TestHelper` (TEST FAILS)

```
...
Successfully upgraded to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: keep-alive, Upgrade, HTTP_UPGRADE: websocket)
Turbo::StreamsChannel is transmitting the subscription confirmation
Turbo::StreamsChannel is streaming from ...
[ActiveJob] Enqueued Turbo::Streams::ActionBroadcastJob (Job ID: 58b516a5-8187-4b70-a02b-0715a8568961) to Test(default) with arguments: "ts_channel_id", ...
Finished "/cable" [WebSocket] for 127.0.0.1 at 2024-01-18 18:35:29 +0100
Turbo::StreamsChannel stopped streaming from ts_channel_id
...
```

By *not* using `config.include ActiveJob::TestHelper` (TEST PASSES)

```
...
Successfully upgraded to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: keep-alive, Upgrade, HTTP_UPGRADE: websocket)
Turbo::StreamsChannel is transmitting the subscription confirmation
Turbo::StreamsChannel is streaming from ts_channel_id
[ActiveJob] Enqueued Turbo::Streams::ActionBroadcastJob (Job ID: 94450a63-1f99-4082-9b54-51991d35db56) to Async(default) with arguments: "ts_channel_id", ...
[ActiveJob] [Turbo::Streams::ActionBroadcastJob] [94450a63-1f99-4082-9b54-51991d35db56] Performing Turbo::Streams::ActionBroadcastJob (Job ID: 94450a63-1f99-4082-9b54-51991d35db56) from Async(default) enqueued at 2024-01-18T17:36:29.217779000Z with arguments: "ts_channel_id", ...
[ActiveJob] [Turbo::Streams::ActionBroadcastJob] [94450a63-1f99-4082-9b54-51991d35db56] [ActionCable] Broadcasting to ts_channel_id: ...
[ActiveJob] [Turbo::Streams::ActionBroadcastJob] [94450a63-1f99-4082-9b54-51991d35db56] Performed Turbo::Streams::ActionBroadcastJob (Job ID: 94450a63-1f99-4082-9b54-51991d35db56) from Async(default) in 15.67ms
Turbo::StreamsChannel transmitting ...
Finished "/cable" [WebSocket] for 127.0.0.1 at 2024-01-18 18:36:29 +0100
Turbo::StreamsChannel stopped streaming from ts_channel_id
...
```

---

Notes:

- No problems in development and production: broadcasting later in background jobs just works.
- Testing by using the `broadcast_update_to` method (instead of `broadcast_update_later_to`) makes the test to pass, but I need to broadcast "later".
- Maybe the issue is someway related to [this one](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/36697) but I'm unsure.